# Can't find Kindle book after download from amazon

Tags: amazon, send-to-kindle

I have just purchased a Kindle book from Amazon and told it to download it to my PC. I can open it and read it offline so it must have it stored somewhere but I can't find it. I'm using Win7 and looked in C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\Amazon\Kindle and according to what I read there should be a folder content under the Kindle folder. But there is not one. 
I opened Kindle for PC and can read the book OK even with the internet connection turned off. All my books are epubs but I could not find this one as an epub or else that is what I would have done. This appears to be very cumbersome.

Comment: The Kindle cannot read `EPUB` format, you must convert to `.mobi`; you can then send those to your kindle.  FYI.

Comment: try also `http://www.amazon.com/myk` and put it into a collection.  then sync your kindle -- should be good to go.  I thought you were asking about `EPUB` for some reaons.

Answer (score 1):

found the location of the files in the tools menu.

Comment: how? where did you click exactly?

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users(your user name)\Documents\My Kindle Content

Comment: That's not where mine is. I can't find 'em.